# Selenium node as LaunchAgent on MacOS

Tags: selenium, service, safari, macos-sierra

Im running selenium node on MacOS  for safari tests.
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
Selenium 3.6.0
Java 9.0.1
Ive configured MacOS to login into account and never go to sleep so safari would work.
Ive configured selenium node to start as LaunchAgent.
I have run.sh like this

```
java -Dwebdriver.safari.driver=/Users/cijoe/selenium/selenium-safari-driver-3.6.0.jar -jar /Users/cijoe/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -debug -log /Users/cijoe/selenium/selenium-safari-driver.log -port 5555 -role node -hub http://{{sel_hub_addr}}:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=safari,version=10,platform=MAC,maxInstances=1, maxSession=1"
```

it has permissions 755 for *myuser wheel*
Ive created **selnode.plist** (644 *myuser wheel*) in `/Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents/selnode.plist`

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>selnode</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>       
        <string>/bin/bash</string>     
        <string>/Users/myuser/selenium/run.sh</string>       
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>>/Users/myuser/selenium/stdout.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/myuser/selenium/stderr.log</string>
    <key>Debug</key>    
     <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>myuser</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

ive loaded it up

```
launchctl load -w /Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents/selnode.plist
```

its running i can see the process and i can see it connected in selenium hub control panel.
But tests fail. It cannot interact with safari.
I can see that process runs as **root**. And i think it should run as **myuser**.
If i run **run.sh** manually everything works very good.
How do i make MacOS to run my agent under other user priveleges?

Answer (score 0):

This is final version of plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>selnode</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>           
        <string>/Users/myuser/selenium/run.sh</string>       
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/myuser/selenium/stdout.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/myuser/selenium/stderr.log</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>myuser</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>staff</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/myuser/selenium</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Ive put it not in global library but in **/Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents**
And ive set permissions to **0600**. 
Ownership of file is for **myuser** **staff** not for root